# Aframe “come here” component. Such that the 2nd entity can find the 1rst entity and animate to it no matter where the user puts the 1st entity

Tags: aframe

How can I create a “come here” component. Such that the 2nd entity can find the 1rst entity and animate to it no matter where the user puts the 1st entity.

I have a button that travels with the user, it’s there when called, it doesn’t move with the camera, it vanishes before teleport and the idea of what I want to add to this is a function where when the user clicks this button (entity ID:One) it will say “come here” to another entity (Entity ID:Two) entity two is listening for entity one to be clicked, and then entity receives entity one’s coordinates, and then entity two travels to entity one.

A longer description of what I am trying to do: Previously I wrote: “How would I write a "come to me" function where one entity calls another to its new location. Lets say that I have a draggable entity, super hands is enabled and the user drags a cube to a new location. Okay so then the user clicks on the cube and a sphere flies to the cube's position but its z (position coordinate z), relative the cube is -1. Then the user drags the cube to another new location, clicks the cube with their laser, and the same sphere from before flies to the cube's new location but its still z -1 relative to the cube. How should I write that? what are the possible approaches? whats the efficient way to do it in aframe? would I create an invisible
child entity on the cube that has a -1 z position? is there a way to look up the global position of a child entity and then tell the sphere entity to update its position to match the child entities position? I would summarize this as a "come to me" function where one entity calls another to its new location.

What I tried: It was suggested that I look at two things 1. The pathfinding component in aframe extras that allows an npc to navigate a mesh during it’s animation, but for this example a simple animation is fine. 2. The follow component (which is 2 years old). The follow component is too abstract for my current level of understanding of aframe code. I don’t understand what it’s following or how to edit it to make it do what I want.

What else I tried: Then I stumbled upon “Interactive image grid in WebVR with A-frame” https://ottifox.com/prototype/2017/09/25/interactive-image-grid-in-webvr.html this makes a camera look up the location of an image, and then move to that image when clicked. Well I thought maybe I can replace the camera with a box and make the box move to another box instead of an image. Well I tried that, and so far it’s not doing anything.

My code is here at https://comehere.glitch.me https://glitch.com/edit/#!/comehere Can you help me solve how to have an entity look up the position of another entity and then animate to it the new location, so that the user can keep updating the position of the new entity, and when clicked the second entity can always move to anywhere the user wants it to move based on where the user puts the first entity.

Comment: I think I just solved it!

Answer (score 2):

You can manually move an entity towards a target, like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cn3f0u91/) (press the sphere). 
The idea is simple:

1) get the target position in a local space

```
targetPos = someEl.object3D.worldToLocal(target.object3D.position.clone())
```

2) move one entity towards another

```
someEl.object3D.translateOnAxis(targetPos, someDistance)
```

3) repeat until the object is close enough

```
var distanceFromTarget = currentPosition.distanceTo(target.object3D.position); 
if (distanceFromTarget > 1) { 
    someEl.object3D.translateOnAxis(targetPos, distance);
}
```

You can throw it into an aframe component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function() {
     this.target = document.querySelector("#target")
  },
  tick: function(t, dt) {
     var currentPosition = this.el.object3D.position;
     var distanceToTarget = currentPosition.distanceTo(target.object3D.position);
     if (distanceToTarget < 1) return;

     var targetPos = this.el.object3D.worldToLocal(target.object3D.position.clone())
     var distance = dt*this.data.speed / 4000;      
     this.el.object3D.translateOnAxis(targetPos, distance);
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<a-box foo></a-box>
<a-box id="target"></a-box>
```

---

You can use the `animation` component like you did, by re-setting the `to` attribute:

```
 // on some event:
 this.el.setAttribute("animation", "to", newTargetPosition)
 this.el.emit("startAnimation")
```

But it gets complicated if the target is moving since not only you would need to get the new position, but also the starting (`from`) position as well.

Comment: Expanded Question: In addition to the original question I’m trying to figure out how to make an entity clone the rotation of another entity at the same time it clones the position, after that I would probably want to figure out how to make an entity clone the scale at the same time it clones the position and the rotation of another entity.

Comment: could something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4uzg7h02/), or [this - without the delayed following](https://jsfiddle.net/4uzg7h02/1/) be ok ? would you like me to elaborate on of those ?

Comment: Looking at the code you gave me I tried to add a scale offset, which worked, and then I tried to create a rotation offset which doesn't work. Can you help me fix the code so it can do rotation offsets in addition to scale and position offsets? Color offsets would be cool also but not necessary. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cloneoffset2?path=index.html:50:7
https://cloneoffset2.glitch.me/

If you want to see that I got a scale offset to work you can look at this https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cloneoffset?path=index.html:22:23 and see a demo here https://cloneoffset.glitch.me/

Comment: Incidentally I was able to adapt my original code, to make the 2nd entity inherit scale, position, rotation, with offsets for scale position and rotation you can see that here https://glitch.com/edit/#!/copy-scale?path=index.html:22:23 demo here https://copy-scale.glitch.me/

Comment: Rotation + scale offsets: https://jsfiddle.net/q9u6vngL/3/ is this better ?

Comment: Thank you very much for writing this, and the past several versions of this. I have learned a lot from studying your code, and while this most recent example seems to be glitching a little bit in chrome (the animation of the 2nd entity seems to get stuck) on ios as I copied it into glitch.me (it might be my error I don’t know) I think the general arc of your code design is illuminating and helping me to have some useful realizations about how three js and aframe work. So a big thank you! I think you have helped me to become a better coder.

Comment: @MicahBlumberg i tried to keep a consistent mindset there, i think there is much room for optimization. Feel free to mark the anwser :)